# How to update data with useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I'm trying to update the data of an array of objects with a specific index. I get the correct names with `console.log(item.name)` but it doesn't change the name to 'Test' for instance. Any help is appreciated.

```
 const [data, setData] = useState(content);
 const content = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "First",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Second",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Third",
    },
  ];

  setData(
      content.map((item) =>
        item.id == dataIndex
          ? { ...item, name: "Test" }
          : console.log(item.name)
      )
    );
```

Comment: [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `useState()` is asynchronous so you won't see immediate updates. Looking at the complete code where you are reading the data state will help to understand your problem.